# De Python a LaTeX

Tags: python, latex

¿Cómo genero una tabla en latex desde Python?

Por ejemplo, de 25 columnas saco el promedio por renglones y luego género el documento latex y compilo dentro de Python. Dejando al final un PDF.

Comment: Hola Amedxy, te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español. Con respecto a tu pregunta, te comento que es muy amplia, porque hay muchas opciones, por lo que te sugiero seguir [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que seas mas concreto y muestres __cómo lo estás haciendo acualmente__. Si solo buscas ideas, te recomiendo que uses Google.